# How can you identify a Craftsman table saw with no ID tag?

Tags: table-saw, tool-identification

I have a 12” Craftsman table saw with a 220v direct drive motor, how can I get the model without the tag?

Only information I have:
it is a 113 series saw motor, model is KK48BR-120
240V 7.0 amps
3400 rpm
1 horse

Comment: Are you looking for the model number simply for knowledge or are you looking to repair/refurbish/get parts? You may not _need_ the model number to get parts for it.

Answer (score 4):

Given the motor model, this is probably a re-badged Sears Craftsman c.1970s. You are lucky, in that Sears Craftsman only had 2 or 3 12" direct drive models over the decades.

The motor should have a source and/or part number on it, and if you search for that against Sears replacement parts you may find the specific model number that this part is for. Doing so, you may find that (for example) this might be a dual-voltage model "113.29970" or similar. Check images online to see if the photos you can find for this model (using the part before the decimal) match what you have, more or less.

If the motor has a source number on it this might match the first part of the model number, with the number after the decimal being model revisions or packaging.

Finding the *exact* model number (including the values after the decimal) may not be possible, but you may be able to work backwards from published manuals to exploded views and features on your saw to get close.